# How to set table headers in Prawn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I'm following [this tutorial](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2008/10/13/how-to-generate-pdfs-in-rails-with-prawn/) to create a pdf file using prawn gem,
and I found [this reference](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Table.html) documentation to generate a table.

How do I set the header row and the header titles to each column?

```
invoiceData = [["foo","bar"]]
pdf.table(invoiceData) do |table|
table.rows(1..3).width = 72
end
```

Comment: Disclaimer: This doesn't answer your question.  I have turned HTML to PDF with Wkhtmltopdf.  WAY easier, though there is a bit configuration to get it set up.  I think I read about a gem being available that uses it.  Maybe that simplifies the config.  I think it's worth checking out.

Answer (score 11):

If you pass :header => true as an option it should use the first row of your array as a repeating header. From the docs:

```
data = [["This row should be repeated on every new page"]]
data += [["..."]] * 30
table(data, :header => true)
```

Comment: Also, try the new "self documenting manual". It's a bit more illustrative than the rdoc. [pdf manual](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/sandal/prawn/manual.pdf)

Comment: If you look at page 85 (I think) in the pdf manual it appears to be working with column headers. I haven't had the chance to actually try it myself yet.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer of @dogenpunk, it is also possible to set the styling of the header row:

```
table_data = generate_lots_of_table_data
table_data.unshift %w(id name address) # add headers

table(table_data, header: true) do
  row(0).style font_style: :bold # header style
end
```

Answer (score 1):

this works for me:

```
pdf.table data, :headers => ['foo', 'bar']
```